# Hexadecimal coordinates for Tile Service in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, tiles, hexagonal-grid

I have an XYZ tile service URL that provides PNG tiles for requests in the following structure: L{z}/R{y}/C{x}.png. However, it appears that the service requires different types of coordinates, which I suspect are hexadecimal.

For example, the URL accepts coordinates like L14/R000017fc/C00002526.

I'm wondering if there's a method to incorporate this tile service into ArcGIS Pro, which typically makes requests using coordinates in this format.

Is there a way to configure ArcGIS Pro to utilize this tile service with the provided coordinates, or is there a workaround to achieve this compatibility?